# folding bikes 20" vs 16" wheels

Tags: tire

I'm trying to decide between 16 and 20 inch folding bike.
any general recommendations, or is it mostly up to preference?

I'm leaning towards 20" at the moment, seems like the best compromise in still getting the compactness but also maybe a little more speed and stability? I haven't tried either so I don't know but from what I've read.
I'd like something that I can get around with, but is also compact.

anyone have experience with 20" it's actually a bit bigger than I thought when folded. Would there be any issues with bring it into a store or movie theater etc, is it still small enough for carry on, on trains/buses etc.?
anyone have experience with it?

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/64191/type-of-permitted-folding-bikes-on-london-trains-tube has a good discussion specific to London.  You may want to check your local public transport company rules.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I own two folding bikes (20" and 26" wheels) and have tried others (18", 12" and I have an a-bike with 6" wheels as a project.)

The bigger the wheel, the more space the folded bike takes up, because wheels don't fold.

A bigger wheel rolls "better" than a small one.  The larger the rolling diameter, the better it will cope with small bumps and irregularities.  The a-bike mentioned above has a hard time rolling on simple chipseal roads, anything but smooth concrete/asphalt is unpleasant.

So its a continuum between "good ride" and "good fold"  The Brompton design does pretty well on both, but you pay for that.

A 20" folded bike is not small, you can generally wheel it about on one wheel  but they'd prevent you carrying much more.   Perhaps you should look locally for one to try out.  Try-to-buy, hires, or borrowing one from family/coworker.  Or check what the local bike shop has.

Answer (score 0):

Note that because [tire sizing is a mess](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html), there are two different sizes called 20": 406 mm and 451 mm. 406 mm is typical BMX size, and is much more common, so you'll have an easier time finding replacement tires, and more variety. 406-mm tires will tend to be fatter. 406 is also much more common than 16" (there are several different tire sizes called 16", but I think 349 mm is most common).

I don't have direct experience with folders. What you may see is that folders built around 16s are designed overall to emphasize compactness, and those built around 20s emphasize rideability, even if you could make a more compact 20. Moultons, which aren't particularly designed for compactness, switched from 16s to 20s with the newer models.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on what the purpose the folding bike is.

I don't use my folding bike as a general purpose bike. I use it when I have to park a car further away from where I'm going due to availability or price of parking spots. I also use it if I'm using public transportation, which means I would have to walk a lot since invariably there is no direct route to where I'm going.

To aid me in these circumstances, I evaluated five alternatives:

- A folding bike
- An electric folding bike
- An electric skateboard
- An electric unicycle
- An electric kickscooter

The electric skateboard has very small wheels (no going over curbs), difficulty making sharp turns or braking abruptly so I rejected it. It however would have been very lightweight. An electric unicycle is way too hard to learn using. An electric kickscooter might have been acceptable, but they have locking problems (usually it's hard to lock it to some solid object and it may lack ignition key so if someone steals it's usable), and available transportation of stuff is limited to messenger bag or backpack (as a cyclist I have a messenger bag which is bit small in some circumstances; a backpack would be more useful with electric vehicles than with bicycles because there's no sweat problem but then I have to move my stuff from messenger back to backpack and back to messenger bag often). Furthermore, electric kickscooters fold to a very long package that often too lack a carrying handle. The volume of the folded package is small but due to its length transporting it may be hard. Also electric kickscooters often make it harder than necessary to repair punctures. Some have honeycomb wheels that can't puncture but they offer poorer ride quality than pneumatic tires. Electric kickscooters can be rented too but the rental costs are surprisingly high if using often, and the rentals are limited to densely populated areas so in many areas rental is not an option and owning one is necessary.

So the decision was between electric folding bike and a non-electric folding bike. Many folding bike options fit very large bags capable of carrying 10 kg without straining your back. I see the increased weight and need to charge (so I can't always store it in my car trunk) as problems of the electric version. Also the time savings of an electric folding bike would be small because I mainly use the folding bike to make short journeys. So I chose a non-electric folding bike.

If your usage of the folding bike is similar, i.e. you use it to do lots of high-value (due to saved time) short journeys you would have otherwise walked combining it with car or public transportation, then the size of the folded package is of huge importance. Usually you have to pay a lot to get one additional square meter of trunk space in a car. For example comparing the price and trunk surface area of Volkswagen Polo and Volkswagen Passat means one additional square meter costs 36 000 EUR more where I live (Finland). A car lasts 20 years so if you have to use a larger-than-necessary car for 40 years, it costs 72 000 EUR extra.

A Brompton with 16" wheels on flat position (so it won't fall when braking) is 58.5 x 56.5 cm, so its trunk real estate during 40 years costs 24 000 EUR. The Brompton itself costs around 1600 EUR.

Some folding bike with 20" wheels would fold to probably around 66 cm x 89 cm, so its trunk real estate during 40 years costs 42 000 EUR. The 20" wheeled cheap folding bike of reasonable quality would cost perhaps half of Brompton, i.e. 800 EUR.

Also if going on a bus or train (usually they have rules against transporting bicycles, meaning large bicycles), there's always a risk that you are forbidden from carrying a large folding bike. A small folding bike such as Brompton takes very little space so the risk that someone throws you out is practically nonexistent.

My opinion on this matter is clear. If I have to use a larger-than-necessary car and pay 18 000 EUR extra for the large trunk surface area to carry a 20" folding bike, and have a risk of being thrown out from a bus or train, to save only 800 EUR in the price of the folding bike itself, it doesn't make sense.

Also consider that most 20" folding bikes fold to a package where the chain is exposed. In contrast, a 16" Brompton always folds in such manner that the dirtiest part, the chain, doesn't touch you even when you stand on a bus with the Brompton between your legs. With a non-Brompton, you have the risk of staining yourself and 5 other passengers with chain oil if using a bus during rush hours.

However, for someone having a cheap second-hand motorhome the economics might be a bit different. Usually the motorhome is so clumsy you want to leave it to a camping area and use the folding bike more, meaning longer journeys and more importance of big wheel size to make the riding characteristics more optimal. Also a motorhome has lots of storage space so the cost of additional storage space with a motorhome is different than it's in a passenger car.

Even though the riding characteristics of Bromptons may be worse than 20" wheeled folding bikes, the presence of a suspension block makes the ride slightly more comfortable than it would have otherwise been on 16" wheels. Also many people ride electric kickscooters with smaller than 10" wheels. Compared to those smaller than 10" wheels, the 16" wheels on a Brompton are luxury.